# Benchmark different kind of SQL database :What's the best test to do?

Tags: database, benchmark

I  have an application that i can configure to get data from different kind of SQL database server, for example Postgres, MSSQL, MySQL, Firebird ...

I must install this application and the database server on windows enviroment, before choice the database server i need to do some benchmarking test to this database importend in all of the supported type of database server for define what's the best choice.

I'm writing a perl script for this job: for test writing and reading speed from this database.

What kind of test i should do to really compare what's the best database server for my app ?

Comment: Well you should check what the most used queries your program will be using and make a code to iterate with it and see how it goes, how long each takes to proccess and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best test, and the only one that is at all meaningful, is to use it exactly as you would in a production environment. Testing it any other way may give completely different and irrelevant results, so write your test script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John Gardeniers - but in order to actually measure the performance effectively you need to look at the transaction times for a simulated workload at the HTTP level - note that the "standard" log formats only provide integer response times - so you'll need to do some tweaking. Also you need to test out how the system behaves with varying levels of load (running single operations on isolation does not reflect what happens when you've got lots of other stuff happenning - speed <> scalability).

C.